# URL.openConnection() method not working on WebSphere Liberty Profile

Tags: servlets, jax-rs, httpurlconnection, httpserver, websphere-liberty

I am using `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` to create and initialize my server.

I am deploying my servlet on IBM WebSphere Liberty server.

When I try to do any REST call, I am getting `401 Unauthorized` error.

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = null;
 String url = "https://someurl/getdata";

    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        String accessToken = this.token;
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token", "bmXaj83sgo4"); } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A `NullPointerException` is thrown or a `401 Unouthorized` error is returned at the line:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

But I am able to hit the same URL via RestClient or using a  simple Java project.

My `web.xml` looks this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

    <display-name>SampleTesting</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Monkey Server</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sample.testing.basic.BasicMonkeyServer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Comment: The code from the question won't compile given url is a string not a java.net.URL. It might help if you provided the actual code, and exception. When getting a 401 have you checked you have access? Is the accessed resource protected and are you providing any credentials?

Comment: @ Alasdair:Thank you for the reply. yes, you are right. I am typecasting the URL from string to java.net.URL.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this code (modified to work) runs fine and authenticates to a Basic Auth protected resource fine from within a servlet on 8557.

Your code or service myst be different. Post the complete code.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the code is working fine. I tried with different credentials and URL  and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the URL I was trying to access and the credentials I used.
Tried with different credentials and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Compilation error

You must have a compilation error when compiling your code, since `url` is a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and does not have the `openConnection()` method:

```
String url = "https://someurl/getdata";
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Try using [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) instead of [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

```
URL url = new URL("https://someurl/getdata");
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Provided you have access to the resource you are trying to request and your access token is valid, your code should work fine.

### JAX-RS Client API

Instead of using [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), I suggest you the [JAX-RS Client API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-client001.htm), which is the standard way to consume REST APIs in Java:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
String data = client.target("https://someurl/getdata")
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        .get(String.class);
```

To perform the authentication, create a [`ClientRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html):

```
@Provider
public class Authenticator implements ClientRequestFilter {

    private String authenticationToken;

    public Authenticator(String authenticationToken) {
        this.authenticationToken = authenticationToken;
    }

    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.getHeaders().add("X-Auth-Token", authenticationToken);
    }
}
```

And register it in your [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html):

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(new Authenticator("your-token"));
```

In the long run, using the JAX-RS Client API will give you much more flexibility.